# My mouse stops working on Ubuntu 20.04.3, is there a fix for this?

Tags: usb, mouse

When I am running: 20.04.3 LTS (linux 5.11.0-46-generic) my usb mouse just stops working randomly, actually the usb ports just seem to stop working.

My laptop is a dual boot so I booted to windows and everything worked fine.

The next thing I did was to boot back to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (linux 5.11.0-44-generic) and everything works here as well.

Has anyone else had any issues like this and perhaps have a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually find an answer but I did reinstall Ubuntu and the problem is cleared up and my laptop is running much faster so it wasn't a complete waste of time.
I would have rather taken the time to track down the problem but was way to frustrated to go that route.